# Can't get instance tags with Ruby AWS SDK after updating packages

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I'm running a script using Ruby AWS SDK on boot. It used to work fine, but after updating the instance with `yum update`, I'm getting empty `instance.tags` when it runs at boot, but when I run it manually, it works fine. The script goes like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new

my_instance_id = ENV['AWS_INSTANCE']

warn "this instance: #{my_instance_id}" # proper output here

instance = ec2.instances[my_instance_id]

asg_name = instance.tags["aws:autoscaling:groupName"] # nil here! instance.tags are empty
```

The credentials are not missing or wrong since I'd get `AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError` or `AWS::EC2::Errors::AuthFailure`. Why can't I get the instance tags then?

Comment: what does `ec2.instances` gives? can you post that?

Comment: @Surya, ok, I'll post in a few minutes when the instance restarts

Comment: @Surya, actually, how do I print it as hash?

Comment: What do you mean how do I print as hash? just post it as output: `ec2.instances #=> { key: :value }`

Comment: @Surya, `#<AWS::EC2::InstanceCollection:0x000000036177b0>`

Comment: just do: `ec2.instances.inspect` and then try.

Comment: @Surya, `<AWS::EC2::InstanceCollection>`

Comment: It should be Hash, are you use that this is what you're getting??

Comment: @Surya, yes, it's [instancecollection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/InstanceCollection.html), it has method `[]`, so you can use it like `var['something']`, but it's not a hash

Comment: My bad, did you try: `ec2.instances.inject({}) { |m, i| m[i.id] = i.status; m }` like posted in doc? maybe it gives you a clarity of what you're getting from the instances?